# Java Google Map

Tags: java, google-maps, gwt

In my profile display form, I have a map that already has the user coordinates and it shows the user location cia marker. I want to disable every click on the map because when the user is clicking on the map, the info window is disaprearing.
Can someone help??

Comment: there must be javascript to close window , check in HTML generated try disabling it

Comment: I suspect that there must be something done deliberately done in your code. I checked v2 and v3 both and Infowindows doesn't get closed if you click on map. If only you can provide the example, this can be answered properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go.

http://code.google.com/intl/ru-RU/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/reference.html#GMap2.Methods

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure for the syntax since i haven't test it but i'm thinking something like that

```
google.maps.event.addListener(dz, 'click', function () {
         return false;
    });
```

Comment: As Fernandes says the default behavior is that info window stays open.And as org.life.java says and i agree is that somewhere in you code there is maybe a javascript part that closes the info window.So  either you search for this part or you can post your code so we can see it.

Answer (score 0):

The default behavior of the InfoWindow is to remain open once the call `infowindow.open()` is made.

Here is an excerpt:

```
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: contentString
    });

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: latlng, 
        map: map,
        animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
        title:"You're around here!"
    });   

    infowindow.open(map,marker);
```

Comment: I only want the info window to remain open even if the user clicks on the map

Comment: ..and it does with the above sample. Also see http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays.html#InfoWindows